# Using getFields to ensure all fields have been set. getValue is returning null but I cannot compare it to null

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-game-engine

Here is the issue

```
public bool Invalid()
    {
        foreach (FieldInfo fInfo in this.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            Debug.Log(fInfo.GetValue(this))          //Log Says null
            Debug.Log(fInfo.GetValue(this) == null); //Log says false
            if (fInfo.GetValue(this) == null) return true; //so this gets skipped
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The objects in this class are mostly GameObject (unity). I am simply attempting to ensure that the level designer I work with knows if they missed a required GameObject from the scene or not.

Comment: is the .ToString() returning null or do you know for a fact the object is null?  Why don't you store the result into a variable and do your logic using that?

Comment: .Log() probably accepts object and does a .ToString().. so it's possible that the an object is being returned but the .ToString() is what is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is:

.Log() probably accepts object and does a .ToString().. so it's possible that the an object is being returned but the .ToString() is what is returning null.

Comment: Yea that's definitely on the right track. If I do  if (fInfo.GetValue(this).ToString() == "null") return true; It works out. Will need to look deeper into the GameObject Class then it seems.

Comment: that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: Casting the the return value from GetValue as a GameObject also works it seems. That's better than comparing the string. Thanks Bro